# How to fix the null problem at the "date"?

Tags: typescript

Argument of type 'Date | [Date, Date] | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date | null>'

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());
    return (
        <div className="rounded bg-night-sky p-5">
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap">
                <div className="m-4">
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={startDate}
                        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                        showTimeSelect
                        timeFormat="HH:mm"
                        timeIntervals={20}
                        timeCaption="time"
                        dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | [Date, Date] | null>(new Date());
    return (
        <div className="rounded bg-night-sky p-5">
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-wrap">
                <div className="m-4">
                    <DatePicker
                        selected={startDate}
                        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                        showTimeSelect
                        timeFormat="HH:mm"
                        timeIntervals={20}
                        timeCaption="time"
                        dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ReactDatePickerProps | Readonly<ReactDatePickerProps>): ReactDatePicker', gave the following error.
    Type 'Date | [Date, Date] | null' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined'.
      Type '[Date, Date]' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReactDatePickerProps, context: any): ReactDatePicker', gave the following error.
    Type 'Date | [Date, Date] | null' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined'.
      Type '[Date, Date]' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Comment: That error comes from "selected" after I implement your solution

Comment: Oh I just fixed it using type assertion. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yeah sure mate.